# Data may not have more than 2 dimensions!

Tags: matlab, controls, analysis

I am trying to do open-loop analysis in some control system.

First, I analyze PT1, and it works fine!

```
% Assigning the variables
Ksys = 0.8667;
T1 = 1.65;

% PT1 modeling
num = [0 Ksys];
den = [T1 1];
PT1 = tf(num, den);

% Step Response
t = 0:0.01:10;
y = 4.5 * step(PT1, t);

% Plotting
plot(t, y);
ylim([0, 6]);
```

But when I analyze the higher order plant:

```
% Assigning the variables
Ksys = 0.8667;
Tc = 1.65;
Td = 0.25;

% PTn modeling
num = [0 Ksys];
den = [Tc 1];
PT1 = tf(num, den);
sh = pade(Td, 2);
PTn = PT1 * sh;

% Step Response
t = 0:0.01:10;
y = 4.5 * step(PTn, t);

% Plotting
plot(t, y);
ylim([0, 6]);
```

it gives the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> plot
Data may not have more than 2 dimensions

Error in ==> TestProject at 25
plot(t, y);
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: what is the output of `size(t)` and `size(y)`?

Comment: `size(t) = 1        1001`
`size(y) = 1001           1           3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out the probelm, it was in pade() function. Here is the final code:

```
% Assigning the variables
Ksys = 0.8667;
Tc = 1.65;
Td = 0.25;

% PTn modeling
num = [0 Ksys];
den = [Tc 1];
PT1 = tf(num, den);
[nums, dens] = pade(Td, 2);
sh = tf(nums, dens);
PTn = PT1 * sh;

% Step Response
t = 0:0.01:10;
y = 4.5 * step(PTn, t);

% Plotting
plot(t, y);
ylim([0, 6]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason `plot` gives you an error is because `y` is a 3D array and it expects a 2D matrix. The second dimension in `y` is a singleton dimension and for all purposes, can be removed. Use the function `squeeze` to get rid of the singleton dimension. Try the following:

```
plot(t',squeeze(y))
```

Comment: Well, It works but the result is exactly PT1 and there is no delay in PT2 response!

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Well, I don't know if the rest of your program is correct as I don't know the context, and so can't comment. I merely answered your question regarding why you get the error "data may not have more than 2 dimensions".